# Access browser Cookies without sending HTTP-request?

Tags: java, spring

I know how to get cookies value from HTTP request with that way

**`> httpReq.getheader()`**

but now i want to access and get cookies values that set in browser wherever and use it in java classes **without sending HTTP request**?
is it possible ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "_without sending HTTP request_"? If a cookie is set in the browser itself, there needs to be some communication to the server for it to know those values.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible ... unless your Java code is actually running in the web browser.  The Java Tutorials include a page on [Accessing Cookies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/accessingCookies.html) in an Applet or JNLP application.

However, if your Java code is running in the web, then you have a problem because:

- most browsers have already dropped support for Java plugins,
- Oracle has deprecated browser-side Java as of Java 9.

---

If your Java code is server-side, then the HTTP request is the only way that information (such as cookies) is passed from the client (browser) to server.  The server cannot send requests to the browser.  The best it can do is send an HTTP reply that causes the browser to send another request.  (Or open a [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) ...)